# I'm an F1 PhD student, but I'm continuing my PhD remotely. Can I work (legally)?

Tags: legal-issues, international-students, consulting, remote-work

I'm doing a PhD at a university in the United States. I am in dissertation status. I am continuing the PhD remotely from outside of the US for the foreseeable future. I am not a US citizen, so am on an F1 visa.

I would like to do some work. Not a lot--just consulting a few hours a week for experience. My advisor is supportive of this.

However, there's the legal question. Generally I would not be allowed to work on an F1 visa, and would need to apply for OPT. However, this law exists to protect US workers, so since I am not residing in the United States, it seems the purpose of the law would not apply in this case. Any work I would do is work that others outside the US could also do.

So my question: does the prohibition on F1 students working applies if they are living and working outside of the US?

Comment: Are you trying to work "in" the US? Or in the country you live in?

Comment: Either. Meaning I'd be interested both in doing consulting for US companies and non-US companies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's](https://international.northeastern.edu/ogs/employment/off-campus-employment/working-outside-the-u-s/) what Northeastern University's Office of Global Services write:

> Students physically working outside the U.S. do not require work authorization from the Office of Global Services. Authorization must be given for work that physically takes place within the U.S.
>
> NOTE: If you are returning to the U.S. while working abroad or on international co-op to perform work for a short period (such as a business trip or conference), this would require authorization.

The same point is made in the answer to a [question at the Expatriates SE](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/3107/2039). But I would still recommend double checking with your university's International Office that it applies to your situation before acting on it.